# rewritecond query_string back-references

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to recover 2 variables from this URL:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id_country=(.*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} language=(en|it)
RewriteRule ^page33(.*) https://www.newsite.ch/page.php?language=%2&id_country=$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, %2 is always empty. I can only seem to back-reference one variable.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's not possible like you try it. In backreferences (`%N` variables) are only data from the last regular expression match.

You can do a workaround with environment variables:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id_country=(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [E=idcountry:%1]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} language=(en|it)
RewriteRule ^page33(.*) https://www.newsite.ch/page.php?language=%1&id_country=%{env:idcountry} [R=301,L]
```

Different solution is to match all variables you need in one regular expression:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id_country=(.*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}&id_country=%1 language=(en|it).*&id_country=(.*)
RewriteRule ^page33(.*) https://www.newsite.ch/page.php?language=%1&id_country=%2 [R=301,L]
```

Note the first argument to second `RewriteCond`... it makes sure, the order of query string arguments will be as expected in the regexp